# NoSuchMethodError for Class File Method toPath()

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, nosuchmethoderror

I'm attempting to copy the file StandardQuestions.csv to a new filename with the following code:

```
String standardQuestions = "StandardQuestions.csv";
if(new File(standardQuestions).exists()){
    try{
        Path source = new File(standardQuestions).toPath();
        Path dest = new File(filename).toPath();
        Files.copy(source,dest);
    }
     catch(java.io.IOException e){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Error: Input/Output exception.");}
}
```

I get an error thrown on the line `Path source = new File(standardQuestions).toPath();` My error message is NoSuchMethodError, method toPath not found in class File. How could the File class not have this method? The program runs correctly on 3-4 machines, but for one user, it always throws this error. Any idea what's causing this? Is there any additional information needed to answer this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `Path` and `toPath()` are relatively recent additions to the Java library (they've been added in Java 7), I'd make sure you are using the same version of Java across the machines.

Comment: Does the user need to have Java 7 installed? It hasn't been released on Java.com yet, should I direct them to the Oracle download?

Comment: @user984165: Yes. As far as I can tell, these methods require Java 7.

Comment: User installed Java 7, problem is fixed!

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes up is that one user is running a significantly different version of Java.  It might be particularly old or non-standard (GNU Classpath).

Have your user upgrade their Java installation version.